# How do you append a filter to the very end of a filter chain from a superclass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, controller

in rails when you register filters in abstract superclasses they come before the filters registered in the controller class. Say I wanted to execute a method called authenticate as a filter right at the end of the filter chain. The only way I can figure it out is to declare that before_filter as the last filter in all my controller classes (and there are many of them). Is there a way to declare this filter in the superclass and have it still be executed last? The reason I want it executed last is that the controller class might modify the authentication requirements just for that controller, and I want these modifications to be taken into account before the final authentication filter is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `prepend_before_filter` in your controller classes instead of `before_filter` or `append_before_filter`.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion too, but I've got a method in the abstract superclass that must run first, and so calling prepend_before_filter on the controller class will push that filter ahead of the one that must run first (it changes the database based upon the incoming url).

Comment: Probably the closest answer but doesn't really answer the original question. I don't think there's a way to do it in rails anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Rails calls your ApplicationController first, before the local one... so you can do something like this (using your example):

In your Application controller you'll have your `before_filter` callback, and a corresponding method that gets called:

```
before_filter :authenticate


def authenticate
  # do something
end
```

In the controller for the resource type you're working with...

You can redefine / override `authenticate`

```
def authenticate
 # do something else
end
```

You can even choose NOT to use your `authenticate` callback for some methods

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate, :only => :my_method_without_auth
```

Comment: Thanks for that but the authenticate method checks certain allowances to see if the current action is 'allowed'. These allowances are set up in another before filter that's called in the application controller. However, say I have a controller where I want to change the allowances further, that can only be triggered from the controller class, and in order for those allowances to be considered by authenticate, authenticate needs to run after the new allowances are set, thus authenticate needs to be declared in the controller class after the other before filter that mod's the allowances.

Comment: Why not have a single before_filter callback ... and use that method to set up everything you need in order?

Comment: That idea isn't really workable. I think filters are there so that you can split out tasks in an understandable fashion. Besides this authentication method is run on every controller. These controllers all do different things.