# add before_filter method to the end of the list in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have before_filter :method in my application_controller and I want this method to run after the before_filter methods in inherit class.

how can I do it?

example

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :run_second
end

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :run_first
end
```

Comment: Duplicate of a question without any good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146987/how-do-you-append-a-filter-to-the-very-end-of-a-filter-chain-from-a-superclass

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the most Rails-friendly way of doing this would be to use `prepend_before_filter` in your SessionsController:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_filter :run_first
end
```